# what does git stash save do that git stash does not do and in what circumstance would you use it?

Tags: git, git-stash

I use `git stash` a reasonable amount and then `git stash pop` to re-apply my changes, typically when I want to do a pull from the remote without losing my changes.

But I saw the command `git stash save` being used in a similar manner and after reading the git documentation I was non-the-wiser on what it does that `git stash` does not do.

Can someone explain to me what it does? (please assume I am a simple person :)

Comment: seriously, -1 already?....tiresome....

Comment: Well it _is_ explained in the documentation. Twice!

Comment: @JonathanWakely I did say I looked at it, I specifically read the "save" parameter of the git stash document - and it did not say anything there. So I missed a part of the documentation, yes, sure me making a mistake.... but then that is the point of this forum, for others to help point out our mistakes. That does not make it a poor question though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git stash --help` says:

> Calling `git stash` without any arguments is equivalent to `git stash save`.

Comment: ah, I didn't spot that... that answers the question thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The synopsis in `git help stash` shows:

```
   git stash [save [-p|--patch] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-q|--quiet]
                [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [<message>]]
```

This means that if you use the `save` option you can also specify other options, like a message to use, but if you just say `git stash` it's the same as `save` with no other options.

The description for `save` says:

> For quickly making a snapshot, you can omit *both* "save" and <message>, but giving only <message> does not trigger this action to prevent a misspelled subcommand from making an unwanted stash.